# .Net Globalization Management

Tags: .net, globalization

We have the potential to have dozens of assemblies that will need to have multi-langugae support, and were wondering how this would best be managed.

1) Maintain one large resource assembly

2) Split it up by our component layers

3) Or a local resource per dll

4) Any better ideas

Also, how would you access these resources across potentially 20-25 apps

Comment: If you have multiple applications using potentially the same resources, aka strings localized in different languages, my suggestion is to put everything in the database and read the strings from there. Are your 20-25 apps distributed to customers or running on intranet and web based?

Comment: @DavidePiras - Intranet/Internet applications. Do you think db calls are faster then a resource file?

Comment: If you load up a hash table of the strings for the current language from the database at app startup or language change, it shouldn't be any slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the established .NET localization model, i.e. satellite assemblies (one per language you support) for each localizable dll in your system.

Note that *not all* of your dlls may be localizable. Ideally only those that deal with the front end contain display text and other localizable content.

If you stick to the norm you'll benefit from the existing Visual Studio localization support (it builds the satellite assemblies for you) and other standard tools and processes that localization vendors are familiar with. If your project is very large, then there will be some amount of localization engineering involved, and it will be much better if you conform to the standard process.